# Improve Website Performance Cache static content issue

Tags: performance, web

I am using webpagetest to know my website  performance.I am found issue with Cache static content i.e. "Leverage browser caching of static assets: 88/100"

FAILED - (No max-age or expires)

How can i fix the issue ?

My htaccess looks like:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesMatch ".(js|css|html|htm|php|jpg|jpeg|woff|eot)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</ifModule>

# Direct Apache to send all HTML output to the mod_pagespeed output handler.
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the deflate settings, you want to add some expiration control to manage the browser caching. I've used the following with good results. Depending on the specifics of the files on your site you might also want to add audio and video files.

From memory, webpagetest likes it when you set the expiry to at least 1 month so you might want to also up tweak the 1 week settings

Good luck!

```
################
# Enable expiration control
ExpiresActive On

# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour"

# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"

# Image files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"

########## End - Optimal expiration time
```

Comment: I tried but getting same msg "Leverage browser caching of static assets: 77/100"

FAILED - (No max-age or expires)

Comment: If you post a URL for the site I can look into it some more for you.

Comment: If you look at the WebPageTest.org results for the browser caching you will see that some of the resources are coming directly from Google and you can't do anything about them unles you try and host those files yourself. There are also some CSS and JS files from your site which you do have control over. You are using CloudFlare CDN. Try going to CloudFlare then domain > cloudflare settings > performance settings. Set the minimum TTL to 1 month, select autominify JS, CSS and HTML, clear your browser cache and double check everything still works well on your site then check WebPageTest again.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 0 second"
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|bmp|ico|htm|gff|html|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|gcf)$">
FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

here is what I have in .htaccess after changing in caches control on my hosting. But even I changed those, it doesn't seem to have any good effect when I run webpagetest.org. I need to wait till the previous caches expire and run it again. It work. hurray!
. here I found a helpful link.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html